# how do i limit my progress bar in javascript to 100% and all the upload should be done before 100%.. where its exceeding beyond 100% now

Tags: javascript, jsp

here is a small peice of code. please help me out ..

```
percentComplete = msg.split(":")[0];
stepNumber = msg.split(":")[1];

if(stepNumber == "100" || stepNumber == "200") {
    doRefresh = false;
    enableButtons();
    $("#progressBar").hide(400);

    return 0;
} else {
    doRefresh = true;
    $("#progressBar").fadeIn(300);
    disableButtons();
}

$("#progBar").html(percentComplete + "%");
document.getElementById("progBar").style.width = percentComplete + "%";
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will the total stepNumber be the same in all cases?

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear why, when using jQuery through your whole piece of code, you use `document.getElementById()` at the end, but never mind.

To fix your issue, use [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) to clamp the value at 100:

```
percentComplete = msg.split(":")[0];
percentComplete = Math.min(percentComplete, 100);
```

You should also consider using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to make sure your `split()`ed value is an integer. Condensed all onto one line:

```
percentComplete = Math.min(parseInt(msg.split(":")[0], 10), 100);
```

Bear in mind, however, that this only fixes the symptom of the problem, not the problem itself. Check your other code and see where you're getting values greater than 100.